# How can I play videos on my TV(not smart TV) from my phone

Tags: video-streaming, mhl

Can I play videos from my Moto G on my Vizio TV via the USB port or HDMI.
If possible, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of devices similar to ChromeCast which plug into the TV's HDMI port and accept wifi streaming from computers/phones/tablets.  Some are quite inexpensive, and a few incorporate a full media computer running either Windows or Linux.  Any of these will let you stream media to any HD TV, even a first year model.

If necessary, you could also use an HDMI switching cable to expand your port count, if all HDMI ports are already in use.